# Explanation of __attributes__ in C programming:

Tags: c, microchip

Having problems understanding statements like:

```
extern volatile SR 
__attribute__((address(0x0042)))__attribute__((__sfr__));
```

and:

```
extern volatile unsigned int SR  __attribute__(( sfr (0x0042)))
```

because I cannot find any detailed technical documentation. Can anybody provide an explanation about these lines of code please, and why it is deemed unsafe?

Comment: What compiler are you using? What does its documentation say?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude :) it is obvious (for embedded programmers) - Microchip. SFR is special function register and address means exactly what it says - it places at 0x42 in the uC address space. It can be also unsafe

Comment: learn about SFRs http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/31006a.pdf and the compiler https://docs.rs-online.com/d88e/0900766b81333261.pdf

Comment: The `__attribute__` syntax originated with GCC, I believe, and has been picked up by other compilers that are either based on GCC or aim for compatibility with it.  GCC's documentation on variable attributes is at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes.  Surrounding sections have info on function and type attributes, and about the syntax in general.  But if this particular attribute is specific to your compiler, then you have to look to your compiler's manual.

Comment: anything that begins with `__` is implementation defined and has nothing to do with C. You must read the implementation (i.e. compiler) documentation